# How to resolve master ip got disassociated issue?

Tags: apache-spark

```
7/04/29 11:39:36 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20170429113936-0000 on worker worker-20170429113809-192.168.5.197-7078
17/04/29 11:39:42 INFO Master: 192.168.5.5:35660 got disassociated, removing it.
17/04/29 11:39:42 INFO Master: 192.168.5.5:35658 got disassociated, removing it.
17/04/29 11:39:42 INFO Master: 192.168.5.5:39706 got disassociated, removing it.
```

I got most of the time when i start spark standalone cluster. What will be reason of **master IP got disassociated**  always and How to resolve this ?